# render Yii2 по наступлению события

Tags: php, yii2

```
echo $this->render('list', ['items' => $this->items]);
```

Как заставить этот код работать после определённого Js-события? Например, клик, докрутка мыши и т.д.?
Можно наворотить костыль, но может быть есть какой-то элегантный метод? Например где-то указав имя js-функции, которую подгрузить к странице.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Оборачиваете страницу в `pjax`. Навешиваете на `onclick` например свою `js`-функцию которая обновляет `pjax` по указанному `URL`.

Comment: да, или как @phpBear, или стандартным ajax запросите что-то по событию, и вставьте ответ куда надо